# Does SQL Server 2008 R2 Express needs a machine reboot after installation?

Tags: sql, deployment, setup-deployment

I have a bootstrapper that chains the installation of the following components:

SQL Server 2008 R2 -> Database Initialization Batch File -> Product MSI

The SQL Server is being installed silently using a Configuration.INI file. No problem there.

The problem lies in the DB Initialization batch file. The batch files calls a two OSQL command, feeding it with a .SQL file (via -i flag) for a database drop and a database create.

When I echo'd the %ERRORLEVEL% immediately after the call to OSQL, the error level is **9009**. I have Google'd for it but no meaningful results came.

I am restarting the service (MSSQL$SQLExpress) after the SQL 2008 installation just to be sure.

Here's the weird part. If I run the SQL Server 2008 installation *before* running the bootstrapper, it works fine. I didn't do anything special, I just installed it (no reboot, etc).

Also, if SQL 2008 is already installed in the machine, the bootstrapper will skip the installation of SQL 2008 and proceed straight to DB Initialization. In this scenario, the DB will be successfully initialized.

Any suggestions about how to proceed?

**EDIT**

After looking into this further, I found this:

> The command interpreter (Command Prompt) sets ERRORLEVEL 9009 when a
>   batch attempts to execute a program that is not found.

So, why is SQLCMD not being found? By the way, I'm invoking the SQLCMD command in the batch file like so:

```
SQLCMD -S <> -E -I <>
```

Comment: I think you'll have better luck on serverfault

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the problem lies in the fact that when a process is spawned, a copy of the environment variables is "loaded" with it. If, in anytime, the value of this environment variables were changed, the "copy" that were loaded to the process will not be updated.

In my case, when the SQL installer got installed, it appended its bin path to the %PATH% variable:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\

But, the value of the %PATH% that was loaded in the bootstrapper doesn't have this path, that's why the batch file returns the errorlevel 9009 (Program Not Found) when it called "sqlcmd".

To fix this, I need to somehow "refresh" the value of the %PATH% environment variable before every component installation starts. I did this with this code:

```
    internal static void RefreshEnvironmentVariable(string variable)
    {
        string latestMachineValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(variable, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(variable, latestMachineValue, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    }
```